# Invalid classes root from intellij for an existing jar in maven local repo

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

As shown in following screenshot a maven library is marked as red - even though it *does* exist in local maven repo

```
/Users/steve/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-remote_2.10/2.2.3/akka-remote_2.10-2.2.3.jar
```

[image]

**But that file does exist on the local filesystem:**   Here it is on the local file system

```
21:43:12/scaladem:35 $ls -l /Users/steve/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-remote_2.10/2.2.3/akka-remote_2.10-2.2.3.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 steve  staff  1277288 Feb 21 21:42 /Users/steve/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-remote_2.10/2.2.3/akka-remote_2.10-2.2.3.jar
```

Here are maven entries in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-remote_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Note also:

```
mvn package
```

works fine from the command line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just happened to me. Re-import didn't work. I solved it by

1. Remove your dependency from the POM
2. Save the POM (assume you have "Enable Auto-Import", if not, check "Import Maven projects automatically" from settings)
3. Add the dependency back

It is basically re-import, but it does the magic for me. Good luck.

Comment: thanks it solved problem on my IDEA, when I checked project structure>libraries, all red underline and if u put mouse on them, there is a notification, 'libraries invalid classes root'.

Answer (score 13):

Intellij IDEA - File - Invalidate Caches / Restart..

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You should also try `mvn install` from the command-line, or install from the Maven Projects sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

If it works from command line, a reimport should work (Right Click on project -> Maven -> Reimport).

Comment: Thanks, I had performed re-import a number of times before posting this.